# Apache Proxypass redirects "localhost:port" as url string instead of local service of the port

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, httpd.conf, proxypass, localhost

### Environment

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

---

I have two servers which are almost duplicates.

`aaa.com.` and `bbb.com.`

They have almost same Apache rulesets.

**`aaa.com.` config**

```
<Location "/serviceEndpoint/">
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8100/serviceEndpoint/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8100/serviceEndpoint/
</Location>
<Location "/fruit/apple">
  ProxyPass "/fruit/apple" "http://localhost:8100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/apple"
  ProxyPassReverse "/fruit/apple" "http://localhost:8100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/apple"
</Location>
```

So `/serviceEndpoint` is a service using 8100 port, and `/fruit/apple`  is a servlet of it.

**`bbb.com.` config**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ProxyPass "/serviceEndpoint/" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/serviceEndpoint/" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/"

  ProxyPass "/fruit/apple" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/apple"
  ProxyPassReverse "/fruit/apple" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/apple"
</VirtualHost>
```

Looks the same, but it's inside VirtualHost:80, if that makes anything different.
(*edit I tested using the same config, but the result was same)

### Problem

Both `aaa.com/fruit/apple` or `bbb.com/fruit/apple` works well.

But, when the service use `response.sendRedirect()`(java) and redirects the browser to `/fruit/apple`,
only `aaa.com.` works and `bbb.com.` tries to connect literal `http://localhost:20100/fruit/apple` from the client browser.

**`aaa.com` redirect response header**

```
HTTP/1.1 302
Date: Mon, 09 May 2022 08:01:29 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Location: /fruit/#!/some_controller
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4EA61F0E6031621E540DBDC9F6C54D64; Path=/serviceEndpoint; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4EA61F0E6031621E540DBDC9F6C54D64; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**`bbb.com` redirect response header**

```
HTTP/1.1 302
Date: Mon, 09 May 2022 08:01:29 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Location: http://localhost:20100/fruit/#!/some_controller
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4EA61F0E6031621E540DBDC9F6C54D64; Path=/serviceEndpoint; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4EA61F0E6031621E540DBDC9F6C54D64; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

### Question

From Apache settings, what can cause this behavior and how should I fix this?

Comment: The redirect does not come from Apache. Configure your Backend service with the proper URL to redirect to.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The redirect path is `/fruit/apple` and service works fine with `aaa.com.` What could causes this discrepancy?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `aaa.com` operates on Tomcat 8.5, and `bbb.com` operates on Tomcat 8.0. Would it affect how `response.sendRedirect()` behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Tomcat difference. Tomcat 8.0 redirects to localhost, whereas 8.5 redirects normally.

Answer (score 0):

That [ProxyPassReverse directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) defines the scope of the URL path(s)  that Apache most correct for in back-end responses to ensure that site vistors are presented with a correct URL that matches their requests to the Apache

```
ProxyPassReverse "/fruit/apple" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/apple"
```

The `bbb.example.com` response redirects to

```
 Location: http://localhost:20100/fruit/#!/some_controller
                                       \
                                        `- "apple" is missing .
```

and therefor the `Location` header is not corrected for by the ProxyPassReverse directive.

That seems like either the back-end application does not create correct self-referential URL's and you need to solve that in the back-end application, or you have made an incorrect assumption and your apache config should be:

```
ProxyPass "/fruit/" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/"
ProxyPassReverse "/fruit/" "http://localhost:20100/serviceEndpoint/fruit/"
```

Comment: `aaa.com.` redirects normally to `https://aaa.com/apple/#!/some_controller`. What could make this difference?